# clear/set interval on hover jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I am togglefading two iframes and want it to stop fading on hover. The following code is not clearing the interval.

```
function mapfade(){
    $('#earth').fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000).delay(3000).fadeIn(1500);}

var fadestop=setInterval(function(){ mapfade () }, 3000);

$('iframe').hover(
  function() {
    clearInterval(fadestop);
  }, function() {
    fadestop=setInterval(function(){ mapfade () }, 2000);
  }
);
```

Help is much appreciated!

Changed glaring error in code to

```
function mapfade(){
    $('#earth').fadeToggle(2000)}

var fadestop=setInterval(function(){ mapfade () }, 3000);

$('iframe').hover(
  function() {
    clearInterval(fadestop);
  }, function() {
    fadestop=setInterval(function(){ mapfade () }, 3000);
  }
);
```

Comment: UM, code makes no sense.... You have all of these delays and fades and you are calling an interval that is shorter than all of those fades/delays added together....

Comment: The duration of the animation (`1000 + 3000 + 1000 + 3000 + 1500`)  is longer than the interval (`3000`). How do you expect that to work?

Comment: well, that was an error. I posted an earlier animation code. I changed it to fadeToggle and it seemed to do the trick. Thanks for pointing out the extremely obvious!

Comment: Are you expecting the animation to stop? it will keep fading since it has nothing to do with the Interval. Is the hover code actually being triggered?

Comment: Yes, the hover is triggering and clearing the animation, and resumes when mouse leaves.